# Is it possible to complete path of peace on Extreme difficulty?

Tags: stronghold-warlords

Stronghold warlords economic campaign "Path of peace" brings us to these objectives:

- Collect Bows (62)
- Collect Iron (125)
- Collect Swords (62)
- Collect Armor (62)
- Lose: Day countdown (41 Days)
- Lose: Lord Dies

Getting Iron in this campaign is the struggle. Total Iron required is 125 + 62 (for swords) + 62 (for shields) = 249 Iron.

There is only single way as per my knowledge to get Iron in that scenario.
We have to demand shipments from Ox-Warlord. At cost of 20 Diplomatic points a requisition for shipment can be done. A shipment is received in 4 parts with a 30 second duration in each part.

After failing same scenario again and again. Tried testing if theoretically it is possible to win it.

Noted below points

o Every 10 seconds we receive a Diplomatic point.

o A day lasts for a minute.

Thus simulated the best possible situation as below.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(){
int Start_days = 42;
int DaysLeft(Start_days);
int Time_in_Seconds_Left(Start_days*60);
int Diplomacy_Points(0);
float Iron_requested(0);
int Iron_Obtained_from_Ox_Warlord(0);
int Interval;
FILE *Output_CSV;

Output_CSV = fopen("Data Into Csv.csv","w");

fprintf(Output_CSV,"Days Left,Time_in_Seconds_Left,Diplomacy_Points,Iron_requested,Iron_Obtained_from_Ox_Warlord\n");
fprintf(Output_CSV,"%i,%i,%i,%f,%i\n",DaysLeft,Time_in_Seconds_Left,Diplomacy_Points,Iron_requested,Iron_Obtained_from_Ox_Warlord); 


// Simulation loop
while(Time_in_Seconds_Left>0){
    // iterating every 10 seconds
    Time_in_Seconds_Left-=10;
    if(Interval>0)Interval-=10;
    
    // Every 10 seconds, a diplomacy point is added
    Diplomacy_Points++;
    
    if(Time_in_Seconds_Left%60 == 0){
        DaysLeft--;
    }
    
    
    // Place a Iron shipment.
    if(Diplomacy_Points>20){
        Diplomacy_Points-=20;
        Iron_requested = 1;
        Interval = 30;
    }
    
    // This shipment is deffered over next 120 seconds
    if(Iron_requested>0){
        if(Interval==0){
        Iron_requested-=0.25;
        Iron_Obtained_from_Ox_Warlord +=3;  
        Interval = 30;                  
        }
        
    }

    fprintf(Output_CSV,"%i,%i,%i,%f,%i\n",DaysLeft,Time_in_Seconds_Left,Diplomacy_Points,Iron_requested,Iron_Obtained_from_Ox_Warlord); 
}   

printf("Iron Obatained from Ox Warlord = %i",Iron_Obtained_from_Ox_Warlord);

fclose(Output_CSV);
return 0;
}
```

And the results are 141 Iron can be obtained via shipments. Thus it is definitely not possible to win this solely relying on Warlord.

Are there any other methods to obtain Iron? (Iron is blocked in marketplace as well).
[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't get the title... is it supposed to be a question?